# Working with NSWindow and NSTextview view using ApplescriptObjc

Tags: appkit, foundation, applescript-objc

I have some ApplescriptObjc code that I have written thanks to red_menance and CJK. I have made some changes, making it into a handler and figuring out how to change fonts and font sizes in the NStextview, but I have run into trouble changing the color of the font and the color of the background via variables.

I am trying to pass a variable value, but it looks like the variable name is being taken as a literal. So how do I get it to accept the variable value? this is just a snippet of the code, if it helps I can post the entire script.

```
set theColor to "white"
set theBackgroundcolor to ""


        if theColor is "" then
            set its textColor to (current application's NSColor's whiteColor)
        else
            set theColor to (theColor & "Color") as string
            set its textColor to (current application's NSColor's theColor)
        end if
        if theBackgroundcolor is "" then
            set its backgroundColor to (current application's NSColor's grayColor)
        else
set theBackgroundcolor to (theBackgroundcolor & "Color") as string

set its backgroundColor to (current application's NSColor's theBackgroundcolor)

end if
```

The errors I get are:
Can’t set backgroundColor of «class ocid» id «data optr00000000E0F1320080600000» to theBackgroundcolor of NSColor.
and
Can’t set textColor of «class ocid» id «data optr00000000E029320080600000» to theColor of NSColor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [key value coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/index.html) to access properties via string parameters, for example:

```
set theColor to "red"
set theColor to (theColor & "Color")
set its textColor to (current application's NSColor's valueForKey:theColor)
```